# Converter uma data para o nome do dia da semana

Tags: php

Estou a receber do meu banco de dados várias datas inseridas pelo utilizador (o campo é do tipo data (yyyy-mm-dd)). O que eu quero, é agarrar nessa data e converte-la para o nome do dia semana. Por exemplo:

```
<?php
   $data_da_bd = "2014-08-13";
?>
```

O resultado seria: Quarta-feira.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O PHP possui facilidades para isso.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Basta usar o pattern desejado ( no seu caso, `%A` ) que a consulta irá retornar corretamente.

Não esqueça de colocar o `Locale` correto ou irá apresentar em outra língua.

== EDIT ==

Visto que sua data está em String, primeiramente é necessário que converter para o tempo.

Pode se utilizar a função http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php

Nesse caso, o final ficaria

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon"); 
$data = "2014-08-09"; 
echo(strftime("%A",strtotime($data));
```

Comment: date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon");
$data = "2014-08-09";

echo(strftime("%A",$data));

Eu tentei isto e aparece o nome do dia de hoje. Não me aparece de acordo com a data

Comment: Sua data está string. Primeiramente é preciso converter para Date. Vou alterar minha resposta

Comment: Obrigado, o problema era mesmo esse.

Answer (score 5):

Uma maneira alterna de resolver o problema é a utilizar a classe [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.create.php) para manipular o formatado da data. `EEEE` em `setPattern()` significa qual será o formato da data no caso é o dia por extenso, para outras opções de formato verifique a [documentação](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$data = new DateTime('2012-03-20');
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('pt_BR', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
                                    IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
                                    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);
$formatter->setPattern('EEEE');

echo $data->format('d/m/Y') .' é: '. $formatter->format($data);
```

**[Exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/emzd-nkag)**

Essa resposta foi baseada em: [php how to format a given datetime object considering locale get default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744952/php-how-to-format-a-given-datetime-object-considering-localegetdefault)

Answer (score 4):

Só complementando: você pode fazer isso utilizando orientação a objetos ou proceduralmente, e a resposta do Felipe se encaixou nesse último caso.
Para fazê-lo utilizando objetos (e a classe `DateTime` do PHP), basta fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
$data = new DateTime('2014-08-09', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Lisbon'));
echo $data->format('l');
```

Comment: Testei aqui, o nome veio inglês, o timezone seria questão de horario, para formatado de data e outras coisas seria o locale.

Comment: @perdeu Bem notado. Nesse caso tem que usar o `setlocale` antes.