# Preenchendo array com dados diferentes, mas de mesmo intervalo em PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte código que está funcionando perfeitamente, porém preciso que os resultados dentro do `$arrayDiasSemestre` sejam '1' para o *monday*, '2' para o *tuesday* e assim por diante...

```
$inicio = new DateTime($start_date);
$fim = new DateTime($end_date);
$fim->modify('+1 day');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$periodo = new DatePeriod($inicio, $interval ,$fim);

foreach($periodo as $data){
    $arrayDiasSemestre[] = $data->format("l");
}
```

Como poderia mudar essa entrada na hora do preenchimento do *array*? Alguém saberia alguma forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se percebo bem a sua pergunta só precisa de usar `w` que é o dia da semana (numérico), em vez de `l` que é o nome do dia da semana.

```
foreach($periodo as $data){
    $arrayDiasSemestre[] = $data->format("w");
}
```

**Exemplo: http://ideone.com/wLeRhX**

Comment: Ele quer os retornos com os dias da semana no lugar dos dia do mês? é isso?

Comment: @ErlonCharles acho que sim, em vez do nome do dia da semana.

Comment: [**Esta**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29694/converter-uma-data-para-o-nome-do-dia-da-semana) pergunta não resolveria?

Comment: @ErlonCharles acho que esta pergunta é o inverso dessa que colocou no link. Ou seja o AP quer um numero.

Comment: Hummm, ok, agora eu entendi o que ele precisa. Ele quer o dia do mês para um dia da semana em uma data. É isso, ou ele apenas quer o número que representa a o dia da semana? Ou o número que representa a ordem da data no intervalo?

Comment: Vamos saber em breve :)

Comment: Era isso mesmo meus amigos! Barbada, não sabia que tinha o 'w' também nessa função... Só que ele usa 0 pra segunda e assim por diante e eu uso o 1 pra segunda... Mas vou mudar no BD e deixar desse jeito que vai casar direitinho!

Comment: @ErlonCharles parece que tinha lido certo :) Vou apagar os comments aqui, se puder/quiser apague também.